# 4 triangles to be aligned vertically

Tags: python, loops, iteration, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

so I'm working on a program where i want the output to have 4 triangles with the lengths 20,40,60,80 placed vertically where the top of each triangle should be exactly halfway along the baseline of the triangle above.

I have managed to get the first two triangles correct but cannot get the top two to align the way I want. I know I am going wrong somewhere but i cannot seem to see it

```
from turtle import *
NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

for shape in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):
    #Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(3):
        forward(20 * shape)
        left(120)
        
   #Move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(20 * shape)
    right(120)
    pendown()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *
import time
NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

for shape in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):
    #Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(5): #redraw some edges to place the cursor on the top 
        forward(20 * shape)
        left(120)
        
   #Move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    right(60)
    forward(10 * (shape+1)) # half of the size of the next triangle
    right(180)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pendown()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the triangle:

```
from turtle import *

for length in range(20, 100, 20):
    penup()
    sety(length + ycor())
    pendown()

    circle(-2*length/3, steps=3)

hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

Here were using turtle's `circle()` method to achieve two goals, first to draw a triangle, `steps=3`, and second to draw centered triangles starting from their top point by using a negative radius.  Beyond that we simply need to adjust the vertical position.

[image]

As far as your code, I believe the problem is simpler than you're trying to make it.  Things get easier if we start by moving forward *half* the length of the triangle, and then build from there:

```
from turtle import *

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

for shape in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):
    forward(10 * shape)

    for _ in range(4):
        left(120)
        forward(20 * shape)

    right(120)

exitonclick()
```

This, in combination with reversing the order of the steps in the loop, and increasing iterations to 4, leaves us centered for the next triangle.